# Unable to select from hive view within a subquery in AWS Glue Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, parquet, amazon-athena, presto

I currently have a glue job that runs some sql code to generate a report. It accesses data from various parquet views, and stores the result in partitioned parquet tables in S3. I've been working to translate our source from one framework to another, both run as glue etl apps. The sql is largely identical to how it was previously, just in a different form. However, on testing the new app, we've found that the application fails when trying to select from a specific hive view:

[image: screenshot_1]

The view in question has no trouble being selected from directly if the sql being ran is a simple select statement, as below:

```
SELECT PRTN_ID     
FROM retail_entmaster1.VACCTBRKCURR_PRT         
WHERE BRKG_CURR_DT_DT = "2022-03-23 00:00:00.000"
```

However, if the view is being selected from in a subquery, like so:

```
SELECT PRTN_ID     
FROM retail_entmaster1.VACCTBRKCURR_PRT         
WHERE BRKG_CURR_DT_DT =        
    (SELECT MAX(BRKG_CURR_DT_DT)   
    FROM retail_entmaster1.VACCTBRKCURR_PRT)
```

Then the run fails, with the above error. I can't find any evidence that subqueries of hive views are unsupported anywhere in AWS, so I'm confused as to why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

convert subqry to a inner join

```
SELECT PRTN_ID     
FROM retail_entmaster1.VACCTBRKCURR_PRT             
join 
(SELECT MAX(BRKG_CURR_DT_DT) mx_BRKG_CURR_DT_DT FROM retail_entmaster1.VACCTBRKCURR_PRT) rs on BRKG_CURR_DT_DT =  mx_BRKG_CURR_DT_DT
```